# Safely change NSLayoutConstraint constant value

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have bottom constraint of my `UIView` object, and i want to change it value. After i did, view did display correctly, but, i see an error log in console;

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003cbe670 PSBApp.KeyboardView:0x7fc5f760e010.bottom == UIView:0x7fc5f4503090.bottom + 306   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c8cbe0 PSBApp.KeyboardView:0x7fc5f760e010.bottom == UIView:0x7fc5f4503090.bottom - 10   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003cbe670 PSBApp.KeyboardView:0x7fc5f760e010.bottom == UIView:0x7fc5f4503090.bottom + 306   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

My code is:

```
private func setupKeyboard(){
    keyboard.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(keyboard)
    keyboardBottomConstraint = keyboard.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: keyboard.expectedHeight())
    keyboard.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    keyboardBottomConstraint.isActive = true
  }

  private func showKeyboard(){
    let bottomOffset: CGFloat = 10
    keyboardBottomConstraint.constant = -bottomOffset
  }
```

So, after i `setupKeyboard`  there is no error and no view visible on screen, then, after i call `showKeyboard` it become visible, but an error appears.

Comment: It looks like you have ***two*** bottom constraints. Is it possible you have called `setupKeyboard()` twice?

Comment: @DonMag yes i did exactly, i did call setupKeyboard() twice by mistake, thanks for notice, now problem is solved!

Comment: I will add that (with additional explanation) as an answer for the benefit of other folks who come across this question.

Comment: @DonMag yes, though it's not exactly rely to AutoLayout mechanics i still thinks that mistake is possible, especially when you set up constraints in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There error / warning message holds the key:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003cbe670 PSBApp.KeyboardView:0x7fc5f760e010.bottom == UIView:0x7fc5f4503090.bottom + 306   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003c8cbe0 PSBApp.KeyboardView:0x7fc5f760e010.bottom == UIView:0x7fc5f4503090.bottom - 10   (active)>"
)
```

As you see, `KeyboardView` has ***two*** bottom constraints which cannot both be valid at the same time.

As per the OP's comments, the `setupKeyboard()` was inadvertently being called twice, resulting in 2 bottom constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Set bottom constraint priority value as High(750)

Answer (score 0):

you can use layoutIfNeeded and setNeedsLayout automatically:

layoutIfNeeded forces the receiver to layout its subviews immediately if required.

Suppose you have overridden layoutSubviews, and UIKit feels that your view requires layout for whatever reason (e.g. you called setNeedsLayout when handling some user action). Then, your custom layoutSubviews method will be called immediately instead of when it would normally be called in the regular UIKit run loop event sequence (after event handling, but before drawRect:).

An example of why you might need to call layoutIfNeeded within a single run loop:

You resize a custom view containing a table view with a custom layout. setNeedsLayout is set so that layoutSubviews will be called later.
A controller object asks the table view to scroll to some particular cell when handling a user event.
Your custom view performs some custom sizing of the table view in layoutSubviews that changes the table view size.
The problem is when the controller asked the table view to scroll (step 2), the table view had bounds that were stale. The updated bounds would only be set on the table view later (step 3). What the controller wanted the table view to scroll to may not actually be visible after layoutSubviews is done. A solution then would be for the controller to call layoutIfNeeded in situations where it knows this might occur.

Comment: i did try to add view.setNeedsLayout()
    view.layoutIfNeeded() but error still exist.